# Sighted man lands in valley of the blind

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for the name of a 1960s (or earlier) - black & white movie - that involved a normal human having an (airplane?) accident and being stranded in a valley of people with no sight.

I specifically remember that it looked as if the actors and actresses who had no eyes had slight depressions where their eyes would be.  These blind people had definitely overcompensated by developing their other senses.

The movie went out of its way to falsify the adage of "In the country of the blind, the one-eyed man is king". He is hunted after they realize he is "different".  He (and his romantic interest) finally escape through a narrow passage in the mountains surrounding the valley to our" normal" world.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152708/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where?

Comment: Sounds like it is based on H G Wells's "The Country of the Blind".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm almost certain this is the Teleplay written in 1962 for the TV Series ["*The DuPont Show of the Week*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_DuPont_Show_of_the_Week) titled "*The Richest man in Bogota*". It was an hour long episode that aired on the 17th of June.

This story is based on the Short Story by [H.G.Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._G._Wells) titled "[*The Country of the Blind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Country_of_the_Blind)"

Plot points:

> The isolated community prospered over the years, despite a disease that struck them early on, rendering all newborns blind.

> Nuñez begins reciting to himself the refrain, "In the Country of the Blind, the One-Eyed Man is King"

As user14111 said in the comments, you can read it online from [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/11870) or listen to it at [LibriVox](https://librivox.org/short-science-fiction-collection-032/)

Here is a still from that episode:
[image: Richest Man in Bogota still]

Comment: After reviewing the short story and the few stills available, I am convinced that this is the story I've been trying to remember for several decades.  It certainly made an impression on me; I was eleven at the time I saw it.

Comment: @YoshiBro, sorry I can't find any video of it, will keep looking though!

Comment: @YoshiBro There is a list of adaptations of "The Country of the Blind" at the  [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Country_of_the_Blind#Adaptations). The story is available at [LibriVox](https://librivox.org/short-science-fiction-collection-032/) and [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/11870).