# Science fiction short story with blind woman one cannot tell is blind

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Short Story of man wandering who comes across area with strange ground, topography. Meets young woman who is barefoot. He eventually learns she is blind but can move without limitations because her world is designed to allow full functionality for the disabled. The story is forty maybe fifty years old.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember where you might have read it?  Magazine?  Anthology?  Check out the [other suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: I have closed this as a duplicate, but that's not a censure on you. It's just part of our bookkeeping so that all of the clues are in one place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might it be John Varley's "[The Persistence of Vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Persistence_of_Vision_(short_story))" as per [Short story about a man visiting a community for the deaf. Ends with them ascending to a higher plane of existence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154614/short-story-about-a-man-visiting-a-community-for-the-deaf-ends-with-them-ascend)?

> A keen drifter describes the dismal political state of the world following a general collapse. He comes upon a commune of people who are blind, deaf, and mute. Much of the story details the culture and personal habits of the people. As their main cultural activity the commune uses different levels of touch-based communication on a regular basis, perhaps 3-4 times a week, in group sessions. These occur after work done during the days. Through these sensory communication encounters the protagonist develops strong bonds with several of the members.
>
> The commune members emphasize mutual understanding to overcome their physical limitations. Their rich use of unspoken/unseen tactile language is used to establish intense clarity about others, a depth of clarity unobtainable using the senses of hearing and vision conventionally. Sex is part of their communication language.
>
> Varley carefully steers clear of representing the blind/deaf commune as a Utopia; they have financial problems, crop failures, criminal justice enigmas, etc. Nevertheless, the commune is clearly free of most of the evils pervading the rest of society. The supposition is this is owed to the unusual high level of communication and sensitivity toward each people achieved on a regular basis. The novella progresses to suggest a higher level of interpersonal clarity and communication is achievable without conventional seeing and hearing; that, being blind and deaf offers unforeseen advantages in interpersonal and even spiritual clarity. The story raises the question, "Is being blind and deaf a handicap, or is it a blessing?" The reader is left to judge.

One of the features of the village is that the paths have raised encoding on them to guide those walking on them with bare feet.

> I bent to the ground and examined it. The light was getting
> bad, but I saw immediately that there were concrete side
> walks crisscrossing the area. Each of the walks was etched
> with a different sort of pattern in grooves that had been
> made before the stuff set lines, waves, depressions, patches
> of rough and smooth. I quickly saw that the people who
> were in a hurry moved only on those walkways, and they
> were all barefoot. It was no trick to see that it was some sort
> of traffic pattern read with the feet. I stood up. I didn't need to know how it worked. It was
> sufficient to know what it was and stay off the paths.

The first person he encounters is a man on a cart, but one of the people he interacts with the most in the village is a young woman with the reveal being the opposite, that she is not blind.

> Everyone seemed so busy that I was surprised to see one woman sitting on a rail fence,
> doing nothing. I went over to her.
> Closer, I saw that she was younger than I had thought. She was thirteen, I learned later.
>
> She wasn't wearing any clothes. I touched her on the shoulder, and she jumped down from the fence
> and went through the same routine as the other woman had, touching me all over with no reserve.
> She took my hand and I felt her fingers moving rapidly in my palm. I couldn't understand it, but
> knew what it was. I shrugged, and tried out other gestures to indicate that I didn't speak hand
> talk. She nodded, still feeling my face with her hands.

....

> "I guess you need the practice," she said, "but if it's all the same to you, could we talk
> mouthtalk for now? You're cracking me up."
>
> I jumped as if stung by a bee. The touching, while something I could ignore for a deafblind girl, suddenly seemed out of place. I stepped back a little, but her hands returned to me.
> She looked puzzled, then read the problem with her hands.
>
> "I'm sorry," she said. "You thought I was deaf and blind. If I'd known I would have told
> you right off."

Comment: Thanks so very much. That’s the title. I’ve been searching for years.